# activeDocument.bitsPerChannel = BitsPerChannelType.SIXTEEN; (WITHOUT MEREGER?) (Extendscript)

Tags: photoshop, extendscript, photoshop-script

I really hope the someone can help out. I just need to change depth from 32 to 16 bit without merging the layers. The code for changing depth is as follows:

```
activeDocument.bitsPerChannel = BitsPerChannelType.SIXTEEN;
```

However, it flattens the image (merges all layers).

I tried:

```
BitsPerChannelType.SIXTEEN.WITOUTMERGER;
BitsPerChannelType.SIXTEEN.WithoutMerger;
```

But it didn’t work. I can of course call an action from the script like I do to apply exposure adjustment layer `app.doAction ("Exposure", "Processing");`. But I want to know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert from 32 bit to 16 without merging use:

```
var idCnvM = charIDToTypeID( "CnvM" );
var desc27 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idDpth = charIDToTypeID( "Dpth" );
desc27.putInteger( idDpth, 16 );
var idMrge = charIDToTypeID( "Mrge" );
desc27.putBoolean( idMrge, false );
executeAction( idCnvM, desc27, DialogModes.NO );
```

Answer (score 0):

Implemented:

```
function exeAction (Type, subType, Value) {

if (Type == 'Mode') {
    var desc27 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idCnvM = charIDToTypeID ('CnvM');
    var idMrge = charIDToTypeID ('Mrge');
    desc27.putBoolean (idMrge, false);

        if (subType == 'Depth') {
            var idDpth = charIDToTypeID ('Dpth');
            desc27.putInteger (idDpth, Value);}
        else if (subType == 'Color') {}
    
    executeAction (idCnvM, desc27, DialogModes.NO);}
}
```

I tested and it works like a charm. I just need to add the rest of the IDcodes. I found this page [Photoshop Scripting & Extension Reference](https://theiviaxx.github.io/photoshop-docs/index.html) which has become more useful than the Object Mode Viewer. I also found the [Photoshop Javascript Ref 2020](https://github.com/Adobe-CEP/CEP-Resources/blob/master/Documentation/Product%20specific%20Documentation/Photoshop%20Scripting/photoshop-javascript-ref-2020.pdf) however neither `Dpth` nor `Mrge` are listed under the Appendix A. Nevertheless, I also discovered the [ScriptingListener plug-in](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/downloadable-plugins-and-content.html#ScriptingListenerplugin).